# Migrating unanswered theory questions to cstheory.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

cstheory.SE has a strict research-level scope and occasionally migrates non research-level questions to CS.SE. The two sites also share parts of their user base; as one of those shared members (who is much more active on cstheory.SE, but trying to contribute to CS.SE) I sometimes find it difficult to choose between the two sites.

Sometimes, this results in asking questions like [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118/55) that would probably generate answers quickly from regulars on cstheory who are not users on CS.SE. Here, the question remains unanswered. Is it possible to migrate theory questions from CS.SE to cstheory if the remain unanswered for a long time and are of a level that might be acceptable at cstheory.SE?

Comment: We could also point cstheory folk to the question; SE makes it really easy to extend your account to other sites, so hopefully they will answer if they see the question (and know the answer).

Comment: @Raphael yeah, that would be a good solution. I have another question on lower bounds in that model that I've been thinking about, so maybe I will ask on cstheory and link to this question. Hopefully the experts will follow the link.

Comment: Asked the [lower bounds variant on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/10958/1037), hopefully this will draw some more users to CS.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be fine, but at least for the time being, where the site is quite new and attracting more users is very important, I would suggest to do this *very* slowly, i.e. give it a few weeks and if it is still not answered sufficiently then it can be flagged for moderator attention.

On the other hand, I think it is fine for OP to repost the question a little bit sooner (maybe after a week?) on cstheory or another site, but the question should be tailored for that site's audience and the OP should follow reasonable guidelines (e.g. OP should wait a reasonable time before reposting, must link in both directions and keep all copies up to date, including posting an answer if it gets answered on one of the sites, etc.)

Comment: Between two Stack Exchange sites, questions should not be reposted. Dual posting separates answers, so someone who sees the question on one site won't see it in the other site. Migration leaves a redirection to the target site.

Comment: @Gilles, I think reposting a question that has not been answered is fine and your points doesn't apply to it. Linking in both directions and OP's commitment to keep the copies up to date is sufficient to avoid the situation you described.

Comment: [Reposting is strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I don't see the advantage over migration in this case.

Comment: @Gilles, I don't think those arguments apply in the case where the conditions I have stated hold. In cases where a question is not answered but it is on topic on [cs.se], I don't think closing it as off-topic and migrating it is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Kaveh does a question have to be closed before migration?

Comment: @Artem, even if it is not closed before, when it is migrated the system will close it automatically as off-topic.

Comment: @Giles Should "Reposting is strongly discouraged." be "Cross-posting is strong discouraged." to bad you can't edit the comment, and deleting will pull it out of order. I will delete my comment in two days. :)