# questions that have been migrated to TCS.se

Tags: discussion, feature-request, features

Ive seen quite a few questions migrated from TCS.se to cs.se. however:

> am wondering about cases of the opposite, ie migration of questions on cs.se to TCS.se. does anyone know of some cases of this? looking for examples...

the stackexchange software is pretty cool stuff in a lot of ways but unfortunately, it doesnt have an easy way to find the migration history of questions etcetera. hope that future versions of stackexchange might have more sophisticated migration features. this becomes more useful/common as there are families of stackexchanges with "near" questions such as esp with computer science etc.

[1] [Migrating unanswered theory questions to cstheory.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/migrating-unanswered-theory-questions-to-cstheory-se)

Comment: There are questions that have been asked here, but then crossposted on CSTheory. [Here's](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/lock-free-constant-update-time-concurrent-tree-data-structures) at least one. I don't know if this could have also been migrated instead of crossposted, but maybe it's of some interest to you.

Comment: my interest is mainly that maybe some questions here could be considered "too advanced" for the generic group & then migrated or "promoted" in a sense based on difficulty. length of time unanswered could be an indirect measure of difficulty. but it looks like there is not much of an inter-group incentive to do this from the cs->tcs.se direction (the groups tend to run like individual fiefdoms although there is some membership overlap) although it has happened many times in the tcs.se->cs "downgrade" direction as that group is quite vehement about rejecting non-research level questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuff like this works on a "need to know" basis, meaning that normal users can't see it. Mods can, though. I see migrations away from us as early as May 2012 (so probably all of them); there has not been a migration to cstheory as yet.

There are a couple of questions that might work on cstheory. So far, we have been reluctant to migrate those away without explicit request of the asker (which has not happened) because they *are* in our scope and our community might yet evolve to deal with them.

Comment: [site:cstheory.stackexchange.com "migrated from cs"](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acstheory.stackexchange.com+"migrated+from+cs") returns no result. So everyone can see that we never migrated a question to CSTheory. It is indeed not a matter of principle, more a matter of such questions rarely arising in the first place and only being migrated at the asker's request.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, I did not think to use Google. :> It is true that the SE platform itself does not readily reveal such information to users, though.

Comment: @Gilles, I think it also plays a role that migration now only works for 60 days, after 60 days a question cannot be migrated. In a sense this can be considered good as since a question that is not really off-topic is not migrated later. On the other hand it is bad from other perspectives, e.g. the idea that a question can be migrated later if it does not get answered becomes more difficult.

Comment: @Kaveh Maybe we should have a review queue a la "Unanswered for a long time" so, say, 45 day old questions pop up there and the community can (again) deal with it?